# Signal strenght different in task manager vs on taskbar

Tags: c#, mobile-broadband-api

I'm using the Mobile Broadband API to read signal strength of my Windows 8 desktop device. I'm getting back numbers that seem to match the signal strength in the Task Manager (performance tab, mobile):

- 0 -> 0 bars
- 6 -> 1 bar
- 12 -> 2 bars
- 18 -> 3 bars
- 24 -> 4 bars
- 30 -> 5 bars

However, the icon on the task bar displays different values. Usually it displays more bars there. For example when I see 1 bar in the task manager, the icon on the task bar displays 2 bars, etc.

Why is that?